# using java in controller and slick

Tags: java, scala, playframework, slick

I want to use java in my playframework controller.

And Want to use slick for persisting data with slick.

I have the evolutions and all ready and slick mapping to a model as well but how to access the model with java?

```
class processDTO @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile]
  with ProcessTemplatesComponent {
  import driver.api._

  private val processTemplates = TableQuery[ProcessTemplates]

  def getAll(): Future[List[ProcessTemplatesModel]] = db.run { processTemplates.to[List].result }
}
```

Comment: Well... you can not use Java code in a `.scala` file. Now... Play also has a Java API... so you can write the parts which you want to write in Java using the Java API and in `.java` files.

Comment: I have a java controller right now. nad now I want to access a Model written in scala and a dao written also in scala.

In the dao I have a getter 

Is can I access the getter in the dao from my java controller

Comment: `import yourpackagename.YourClassname;`  ??

Comment: do I have to need a Database provider in java?

Comment: I have added the scala function which I want to use in my java controller. I did the import you mentioned

Comment: but how to call the function now? tried to make a new instance

Comment: by following the way that function is supposed to be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well....

YourScalaClass.scala

```
pakcage yourscalapackage

class YourScalaClass(s: String) {

  def doSomethingAndReturnString(): String = "omg :: " + s

}
```

YourJavaClass.java

```
package yourjavapackage;

import yourscalapakcage.YourScalaClass;

public class YourJavaClass {

  public void do() {
    YourScalaClass ysc = new YourScalaClass("lol");

    String str = ysc.doSomethingAndReturnString();

    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: thats exactly what I do. But then is the problem with the `(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider`

Comment: take care of all that in Scala code itself... keep the cross-language "functions" as simple as possible.

Comment: can I use the databaseconfigprovider in java as well?